# Missing ConnectionManager namespace in BIDS 2008R2 Script Task

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids, script-task

I recently had to rebuild the operating system (Windows 7 Pro x64) on my development machine and reinstalled SQL Server 2008 R2 with all options for SSIS then applied SP3 and installed both SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility x64 and the SP3 features pack.

Years ago, I built several SSIS packages that use script tasks that still work successfully on my live server.

I began to develop a new package in the past few days that uses a script task but no matter what I do, I can’t access the ConnectionManager namespace.  I get the following error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'ConnectionManager' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Users\billiam904\AppData\Local\Temp\SSIS\ST_ed212cb80f8a44818d8dcd3d60dff63c\ScriptMain.cs   52  13  ST_ed212cb80f8a44818d8dcd3d60dff63c

I have the following declared:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

But when I try to declare a ConnectionManager object, I get the error above.
I feel like either SP3 has messed me up or I am missing a prerequisite.

The differences between my live server and my development machine is that SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 is installed on my server and SQL Server 2008 R3 is installed on my development machine.  My development machine also has SQL Server 2014 installed but I am using BIDS 2008.

I’d appreciate it if anyone can give me some ideas. Thanks.